# Pacing formula: Subtract dates in different cells and compare number

Tags: excel, date, compare, percentage

I have an excel spreadsheet (with no set number of rows) with a start date in column G, an end date in column H, a number of units sold in column I, and a number of total units available in column J.  I would like to create a macro that:

1) Subtracts the start date from the end date to get a total number of days

2) Subtracts the start date from todays date to get a total number of days 
   running

3) Divides the total number of days running from the total number of days to 
   get a percentage of days running

4) Divides the total units sold from the total units available to get a 
   percentage sold

5) Compare the total days running percentage to units sold percentage:

A) If percentage of units sold is equal or greater than the percentage of 
  days running, write "Ahead of Pacing" in Column K

B) If percentage of units sold is less than the percentage of days running, 
      write "Behind Pacing" in Column K

*** Update: I've included some links to pictures of how I would like the spreadsheet to work (Sorry, I don't have enough reputation points to post pictures):

Before:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/f35lx1gtsq296s2/Sheet1.jpg?dl=0

After:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/clnnxm6eteav5kz/Sheet2.jpg?dl=0

Thanks

Comment: What *specifically* is the problem you're having?  What have you tried, and what is preventing you from achieving your goal?  If you can't explain that, it's unlikely someone is going to write this for you.

Comment: Hey Tim... Thanks for your reply.  I updated my original post w/ links to some pics of how the sheet looks & how I would like it to look after (sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post images).  Basically I have a giant sheet of vendors that release products to stores for a given amount of time.  I'm trying to create a macro that goes to each "total row" (gray rows)... and calculate how many products need to be sold to reach our deadline (I came up with the wording for how the formula should work in my original post).  The amount of rows change, so I'd need it to use End(xlup).  Thanks:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, once again I suppose I'll answer my own question... maybe somebody else will find it useful.  It's upsetting that I can never seem to get a straight answer on this forum.  So far I've had one member ask me what program I'm using (when I clearly mentioned spreadsheets in my question... that should clearly indicate that I'm using Excel)... and another who berates me like a teacher to a student (and yet provides no useful information).  I'd rather get no response than have to endure these impudent remarks from people who can't understand/read a question.  I know it's not me because I've had no trouble getting help from mrexcel.com, rondebruin, and several other forums in the past (looks like I'll be heading back to those forums from now on).  Anyways, all complaints aside here's the code I was looking for:

```
Sub Pacing()
' Reps must put a date in or it breaks the macro (can't use NA or Month Names)
Dim i As Long
Dim numberOfRows As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Worksheets("Pacing").Activate

numberOfRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

' Bottom Rows first
Cells(numberOfRows, 11).Value = Cells(numberOfRows, 8).Value - Cells(numberOfRows, 7).Value
Cells(numberOfRows, 12).Value = Now() - Cells(numberOfRows, 7).Value
Cells(numberOfRows, 13).Value = Cells(numberOfRows, 12).Value / Cells(numberOfRows, 11).Value
Cells(numberOfRows, 14).Value = Cells(numberOfRows, 9).Value / Cells(numberOfRows, 10).Value

If Cells(numberOfRows, 14).Value = Cells(numberOfRows, 13).Value Then
 Cells(numberOfRows, 15).Value = "Pacing"
 Cells(numberOfRows, 15).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 180, 10)
ElseIf Cells(numberOfRows, 14).Value > Cells(numberOfRows, 13).Value Then
 Cells(numberOfRows, 15).Value = "Ahead of pacing"
 Cells(numberOfRows, 15).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 180, 10)
ElseIf Cells(numberOfRows, 14).Value < Cells(numberOfRows, 13).Value Then
 Cells(numberOfRows, 15).Value = "Behind pacing"
 Cells(numberOfRows, 15).Interior.Color = RGB(182, 0, 24)
End If

 If Cells(numberOfRows, 10).Value > Cells(numberOfRows, 5) Then
 Cells(numberOfRows, 16).Value = "Warning: Total Cap Greater Than Goal"
 Cells(numberOfRows, 16).Font.Color = RGB(182, 0, 24)
 ElseIf Cells(numberOfRows, 10).Value < Cells(numberOfRows, 5) Then
 Cells(numberOfRows, 16).Value = "Warning: Total Cap Lower Than Goal.  Speak with Rep"
 Cells(numberOfRows, 16).Font.Color = RGB(182, 0, 24)
End If

'Continue Up

For i = numberOfRows To 3 Step -1


If Cells(i, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192) Then
Cells(i, 11).Value = Cells(i, 8).Value - Cells(i, 7).Value
Cells(i, 12).Value = Now() - Cells(i, 7).Value
Cells(i, 13).Value = Cells(i, 12).Value / Cells(i, 11).Value
If Cells(i, 10) = 0 Then
Cells(i, 14).Value = 0
Else
Cells(i, 14).Value = Cells(i, 9).Value / Cells(i, 10).Value
End If
  If Cells(i, 14).Value = Cells(i, 13).Value Then
 Cells(i, 15).Value = "Pacing"
 Cells(i, 15).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 180, 10)
 ElseIf Cells(i, 14).Value > Cells(i, 13).Value Then
 Cells(i, 15).Value = "Ahead of pacing"
 Cells(i, 15).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 180, 10)
 ElseIf Cells(i, 14).Value < Cells(i, 13).Value Then
 Cells(i, 15).Value = "Behind pacing"
 Cells(i, 15).Interior.Color = RGB(182, 0, 24)
 End If

 If Cells(i, 10).Value > Cells(i, 5) Then
 Cells(i, 16).Value = "Warning: Total Cap Greater Than Goal"
 Cells(i, 16).Font.Color = RGB(182, 0, 24)
 ElseIf Cells(i, 10).Value < Cells(i, 5) Then
 Cells(i, 16).Value = "Warning: Total Cap Lower Than Goal.  Speak with Rep"
 Cells(i, 16).Font.Color = RGB(182, 0, 24)
 End If

 End If
 Next i

 End Sub
```

Again, hopefully this will help others out at least a little... there's still some formatting I need to take care of after running the macro, but otherwise it does the job.